# How am I supposed to loop big files in openpyxl? iter_rows gives errors

Tags: python, excel, selenium, openpyxl

I have been building a web scraper in python/selenium/openpyxl as part of my job for the last two months. Considering it's my first time doing something like this it has been relatively successfull, it has produced results. But one thing that I have never been able to figure out how to do properly is, how am I supposed to loop through an .xlsx document?

I am working with files with 500k+ rows. I have split them up to 100k each though so that the size wouldn't become an issue.

So my problem is, when I loop through the document in this way:

```
wb = load_workbook(filePath, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

while (currentRow <= docLength):
    adress = ws.cell(row=currentRow, column=1)
    car = ws.cell(row=currentRow, column=2)
        
    #Scrape info and append into other document
    currentRow += 1
```

It ends up consuming way too much memory, and the script goes very much slower already after 100 rows...

But if I do this, I get ParseError after a few hundred rows every time! It's very frustrating, as I think this is the right way to do it.

```
wb = load_workbook(filePath, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

try:
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=10, max_row=docLength, values_only=True):
        for x, cell in enumerate(row):
            if x == 0:
                adress = cell
            if x == 1:
                car = cell

        #Scrape info and append into other document
        currentRow += 1

except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
    ???
```

The full exception error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\scrape.py", line 263, in <module>
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=10, max_row=docLength, values_only=True):
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.0.3-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\_read_only.py", line 78, in _cells_by_row
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-3.0.3-py3.8.egg\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 142, in parse
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1227, in iterator
    yield from pullparser.read_events()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1302, in read_events
    raise event
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1274, in feed
    self._parser.feed(data)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 769027
```

Why is this happening? :(
And why is it saying such a high column number, is it because of the xml formating?

Comment: are you necessarily tied to using excel as a data store? It's not really what it's good at and interfacing with python really isn't great. Even a local sqllite db will be much faster

Comment: Well not necessarily, as long as I can give my boss the results in an excel file later, which I assume won't be a problem. What is the easiest and best solution? sqlite db? xml file? I am a beginner in python so I don't want a solution that is too much to learn. But thank you.

Comment: Without looking at your data, the easiest solution would be to write to a plain text file with your columns separated by a comma or tab. Excel can read these file natively anyway, but obviously depends how complex your scraped data is. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

Comment: Don't use `ws.cell` in read-only mode! This is what is making your code code run slow. As for the exception, it looks like there is a problem with your file. Can't say more about it without looking at the file.

Comment: Charlie, thank you.
ol_oso, thank you very much, this seems like a good solution. Is f.write the fastest way to read a big file like this with python?

Comment: probably not the fastest but more than fast enough. Unless you've got a seriously fast internet connection and are running asynchronous web requests you won't be limited by reading/writing to a plain text file. ```f.write``` should be able to write data close to the maximum speed of your storage drive. The other major benefit is that it's very simple to make fast